# line segment closed set

Tags: general-topology

[image]

Just want to confirm if C is also compact. The answer given is B but I reckon C is also compact since it is both closed and bounded. Thank you!

Comment: Yup C) is just the points on the x-axis from [1,2] which is closed and bounded

Comment: Well, $C$ is the product of that a closed interval and the singleton $\{0\}$. However, both are compact, hence the product is compact by Tychonoff's theorem, and the both are bounded, hence the product is bounded. So the product is indeed compact in $\mathbb R^2$.